# Как правильно настроить диалог в unity?

Tags: unity3d, canvas, dialog

Есть `RequestManager` скрипт с `callback`, где выполняются запросы.
Для одной сцены внутри `Canvas` я создал объект `CustomDialog` (по умолчанию выкл), где есть текстовое поле и кнопка.
Я не хочу добавлять объект `CustomDialog` в каждую сцену в `Canvas`, где есть запросы.
Можно ли добавлять или создать при необходимости этот объект диалога и управлять им внутри `RequestManager` скрипта?